# Go Appengine Debug ability

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I searched on this forum and I can't seem to find much information about Go AppEngine debug method.

I come from Java world. I usually put a Java web app on Tomcat and turn on the debug port. Then I use Eclipse to have remote debugging. I am wondering if there is similar features or ability in Go AppEngine?

Comment: tomcat  != appengine :)

Comment: At this time, the beta Cloud Debugger, https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/ , supports Go only on Compute Engine -- on App Engine, it only supports Java. I do not know of an alternative, sorry:-(.